# How to cast arrays to a type?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, casting, sql-in

I want this query to return all ids and associated emails that are NOT returned by query #2:

```
select my_table.id, my_table.email
from my_table join another_table on my_table.id=another_table.mytable_id
where my_table.id not in (select array (select my_table.id 
             from my_table join yetanother_table 
             on my_table.id = yetanother_table.mytable_id 
             where yetanother_table.time1 between '2015-01-26T08:00:00.000Z'
                                              and '2015-02-02T07:59:59.999Z'
             group by my_table.id))
```

When I run it, I get the following error near the select in line 3:

> ```
> operator does not exist: integer = integer[]   
> You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

I tried casting the array to integer and got this:

> ```
> cannot cast type integer[] to integer
> ```

I also tried casting both `my_table.id` and the array to `varchar`. That got rid of the error but returned fewer rows than I expected!

First questions: Why can't I cast `integer[]` to `integer`? What is the default data type of an array? Is there a cleaner way to get rid of the "operator does not exist" error than casting both my_table.id and the array to `varchar`?

And following up: now I'm wondering why I'm getting too few rows. Does it look like the way I wrote it will return what I want? i.e. all ids that are not returned by query #2?

Another constraint - I need to do everything with one statement.

Comment: Just get rid of the `select array(` part. You don't need that when using an `IN` operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you remove the misplaced [array constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS), you get a working query.
The [`IN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN) and [`NOT IN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-NOTIN) constructs require a plain subquery to the right yielding matching types - *not* an array.

The query is still twisted and inefficient, though. Use instead:

```
select m.id, m.email
from   my_table m
join   another_table a on a.mytable_id = m.id
left   join yetanother_table y on y.mytable_id = m.id
                              and y.time1 >= '2015-01-26 08:00'
                              and y.time1 <  '2015-02-02 08:00'
where  y.mytable_id IS NULL;
```

More information:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the `select array`. The `IN` operator is looking for a single column query result, not an array.